# If i want to make an application compatible with tablet and mobile device

Tags: android

If i want to make an application compatible with tablet and mobile device, should i create one project for mobile devices and another for tablet of use the same screen project for both if so how ? thanks for your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely use one project for both, except for when they have totally different functionalities. 
You can adapt the looks of your App for every device type within that project by providing different layout files for different screen sizes. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article.

Comment: if the project have the same functionalities then i can do both in one project is that it

Comment: Yes. If you would have 2 projects, every change you made to your code you have to do in both projects. That would be terrible to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single apk for both phones and tablet.

Have a look at the link below

http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

There's quote in the above link  whcih says
**We encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible, doing so is sometimes not possible**

So make a application that support as many devices as possible. Consider having multiple apk's only if required.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html
For example, the following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

Design different layouts for different screen sizes

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")  
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

main_activity.xml for both handsets and tablets

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For tablets
```

Also have a look at the link below for multiversioning

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZM8oZBgfk

http://gargengineer.blogspot.in/2012/02/creating-android-phone-tablet.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to create a single project for all the devices you want to support. There are some guide lines you have to follow in order to support different screen size and resolutions. You already know one of the biggest problem during app developing is the device fragmentation. So you can implement different layouts under res/layout dir. You have to design at least layout, layout-small, layout-large, layout-xlarge. Keep in mind that the display orientation can change so you should implement also layout-land and so on.
Regarding images you have to create different images for different device screen density. 
**You can use new selector like layout-swxxxdp where xxx is the resolution.**
In particular under res/drawable res/drawable-mdpi res/drawable-ldpi res/drawable-hdpi. You can support more screen density too.
**It can happen that using different layouts isn't enough for your application. So you can consider using fragments that give to you more freedom and you can re-use your code.**
You can mix layout and fragments to have more control on the layout. Expecially if you want to support tablet and smart phone i suggest you to use fragments. 
For more information you can give a look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html) and [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/03/android-fragment-tutorial-webview-example.html) for fragments.

Comment: Quoting your answer: "you have to create a single project for all the devices you want to support" -- Google does not appear to share your point of view, see [support for different APKs of thje same app for differently featured devices](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) as rreferred to in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16031098/1856738).

Comment: Well if you read carefully it is written "Although we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible, doing so is sometimes not possible". There are some situation where this is impossible like different CPU Architecutre (see NDK) diffent OPEN GL version. But if you "simply" support different screen size and density you have to create only one project.

Comment: Exactly. And if you read your post carefully then you wrote "you have to", which means "you must", which is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

use different resource/layout folder for different screen size.Their is no need to create separate project for tablet and mobile device.Make use of Nine-patch Image that automatically resize based on screen size of device in android.

Answer (score 0):

There is [support for different APKs of thje same app for differently featured devices](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

The key question is, can you think of a way to make your app look good with the same or a modular user interface on small screens and on large screens. Also, you might want to come up with a high-end version which only runs on more powerful devices.

There *are* cases where you will want to have different APKs, though you have to be aware of the costs.

In practice, though, if you look at many apps on the market, the developers simply had no clue how to deal with different screen sizes elegantly.

Regarding your comment above, *if it has thje same functionality*: That is *not* the key question if you ask me. Although it depends what you mean by *functionality*.